# Serial port initialisation for python 2.7 in ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7, arduino, serial-port, ubuntu-14.04

I want to read the serial data from arduino in python in ubuntu operating system. The arduino application is running fine but when I open the same port in python in my case port is '/dev/ttyACM0' is not opening. I have tried to change the permissions of the port. But still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

It could be an [old bug in the Linux kernel](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1501240) so, try to update your Ubuntu 14.04...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a usb to serial converter, like its built in on arduino development boards, it should usually be something like /dev/ttyUSB0.

Also make sure you are in the dialout and tty group:

```
usermod -aG tty $USERNAME
usermod -aG dialout $USERNAME
```

Your program should look something like this:

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial()
ser.port="/dev/ttyUSB0"
ser.baudrate=9600
ser.open()
ser.write("hello world")
```

Can you show us your program?